# I'm getting import error when I'm trying to connect Python and Electron.js

Tags: javascript, python, electron

I'm writing python program with Pybluez library and I want to connect my Python script with `Electron.js` but the problem is I'm getting import error. 
Does anyone know how to fix it?

I'm new to javascript and electron.js. Thank you.

Here is javascript code :

```
const ElectronTitlebarWindows = require('electron-titlebar-windows');
const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");



//----------------Functions------------------------------------------------
function createWindow () {
    window = new BrowserWindow({width: 900, height: 600,icon: 'pressure.png'})
    window.loadFile('index.html')
    window.setMenu(null)
    PythonShell.run('SensorApp.py', null, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('finished');
    });

  }


  app.on('ready', createWindow)
  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit()
    }
  })
```

Here is my python code :

```
import bluetooth
import sys
class BTcommucation():
    def find_device(self):
        devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
        print("I have found " + str(len(devices)) + " devices!")
        for address, name in devices:
            print(address + " " + name)    

    def connect_device(self,addressMAC, port=1 ):
        socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
        socket.connect((addressMAC, port))
        while(True):
            print("Enter your command:")
            text = input()
            if text == "quit":
                break
            socket.send(text.encode())
        socket.close()
        print("Connection lost or quit")



bt_adapter = BTcommucation()
bt_adapter.connect_device('98:D3:37:00:A9:26')
```

This is the error I'm getting :

[image: error]

Comment: Do you have a module installed and that you can access called `bluetooth`? Does running the python code by itself work? If so is the environment you running it in different from how your JavaScript file calls it?

Comment: Yes, I installed Pybluez and it works by itself fine, but when I type npm start I'm getting this error. I have all my files in one directory. I installed Pybluez via pip install.